# SNR of μ-law companding

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, signal-synthesis, quantization, digital-to-analog

I know the snr after  μ-law compression is

$\text{SNR}\approx\frac{3L^2}{[\ln(1+ \mu)]^2}$
when  $\mu \gg \frac{\max_t m(t)}{\text{rms}(m(t))}$,

where $m(t)$ is the message signal, and
$L$ the number of levels.

Can anyone give the idea how it came or the proof?

Comment: I don't understand. Your "mp" or  $a$ is both time-variant, so it needs to be $a(t)$, and it actually **is** the message signal $m(t)$, isn't it?

Comment: mp is the maximum value of the message signal m(t)